# SQL Server Configuration Manager not showing in windows 10

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have reset/formatted the system, then I installed Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2019, but I am not able to connection SQL Server. Then I followed this link
https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/where-is-sql-server-configuration-manager

But in step 3: SQL Server Configuration manager /SQLServerManager15.msc not able find in add or Remove Snap-ins popup window in my system.

What I should do?

Comment: Did you *actually* install SQL Server? The fact you tagged SSMS, not SQL Server suggests you thing SSMS is SQL Server; it is not.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to View, Server Explorer, Data Connections.  You can see existing connections there.

[image]

Or you can create a new connection. If MSSQL is properly installed then you can put in localhost for the server name and connect.

[image]